# Mac App Store shows OS X Lion installed after interrupted connection

Tags: macos

I purchased Lion from the Mac App Store and for some reason my connection got cut, after that Mac App Store says that the app is INSTALLED when i can't see it anywhere.

I tried to check for unfinished downloads but it still says: INSTALLED

I should note that i'm on Lion GM and the installer was downloading in LaunchPad, but i can't see it anymore

i tried:

- Rebuilding LaunchServices
- Look for the installer

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Also off topic - we're not answering GM questions in general as they are not publicly available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select any tab in the App Store except for purchase and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down when you select purchased, you can re-download the Lion installer.

Using spotlight may also reveal that you have the installer somewhere on the mac - even an external drive and might avoid the delay and bandwidth use to download the installer again.

Comment: where is that? holding the option key doesn't do anything on Mac App Store Purchased tab or the Mac OS X Lion tab

Comment: In the App Store - I'm not at a Lion mac presently - but it should say installed instead of $29 http://cl.ly/8fuM

Comment: nothing happens when i push hold option while clicking the installed button http://cl.ly/0j3P3U0c0N2S132Q0M3z

Comment: found this: http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/20/install-lion-final-release-over-lion-gm/ ... thanks

Comment: I'll incorporate that clarification in my answer. I didn't need to do that, but I have debug mode turned on. Perhaps my testing wasn't sufficient for everyone's needs. Big thanks for the feedback.